# Database design : how to properly implement steps of a project in a database

Tags: database-design

Currently designing a database for project management, I will have to encode several projects passing through several steps. The steps that each project goes through are not always similar.

I have thus planned to create a table (let's call it **TABLE A**) listing in a comprehensive manner the **theoretical steps**, with a primary key for each step and some additional information such as the mean time spent by the company to usually perform the step, the group/service that will always lead the step,...

In another table (**TABLE B**), I have planned to store each **project**.

I would like to link the steps from TABLE A to each project in TABLE B by encoding a date corresponding to the start date of the step of the considered project.

How can I do it properly ?

Comment: It might be worthwhile to mention that the relationship between steps and projects is many-to-many.  That is, each project can have many steps and each step can be part of many projects.  If that is, indeed your case, that suggests the design.

Comment: One option is to have a set of tables with your theoretical project models and another set of tables with actual project information **copied** from the theoretical project modules.  This allows you to change the theoretical project models without changing any actual projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have two tables `Step` and `Project` holding information about the respective concepts, both table holds Primary Keys constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE Step(
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  -- Step data
);

CREATE TABLE Project(
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  -- Project data
);
```

Create a third table `Planning` that will perform the **Many-to-Many** mapping between `Step` and `Project` and eventually stores relevant data such as `start` and `stop` dates.

```
CREATE TABLE Planning(
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  step_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  project_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  start DATETIME NOT NULL,
  stop DATETIME NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(step_id) REFERENCES step(id),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(project_id) REFERENCES project(id),
  UNIQUE(step_id, project_id),
  CHECK(start < stop),
  -- Planning data
);
```

This table will reference `Step` and `Project` through Foreign Key constraints.
It will be something like:

```
Steps <-- Planning --> Project
```

Then you can generate current and future planning steps for all projects by joining tables together:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    step JOIN planning ON (step.id = planning.step_id)
         JOIN project  ON (project.id = planning.project_id)
WHERE
   planning.stop >= (now() - "15 days"::INTERVAL)  -- only ongoing or recent project steps
```

Finally you can perform a **Pivot** operation (sometimes referenced as cross analysis) to get this record set as rectangular array where project and step dimensions are orthogonal.

This final step may not be available and depend of your Database Engine. This is mainly because RDBMS enforces names and types on columns and allow freedom over rows.

Anyway there are a lot of software available to perform and render such analysis.